# Modifying model in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm putting together an app that displays a list of stores (with add/edit/delete options), and clicking on a store name takes you to the list of items in that store (again with add/edit/delete).
The model:

```
// app/models/shop.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
   shopName: DS.attr('string'),
   shopDetails: DS.attr('string'),
   shopStock: DS.attr('array', {
      defaultValue() {
          return [];
      }
  })
});
```

Basically model should be as:

```
{
    "shopName": "someName",
    "shopDetails": "someDetails",
    "shopStock": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "description": "bar",
            "price": "555"
        }
    ]
}
```

For each shop the route is dynamical:

```
// app.router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('shop', function() {
      this.route('stock', { path: '/:shop_id/stock' });
      this.route('edit', { path: '/:shop_id/edit' });
  });
});
```

And in the controller I have:

```
actions: {
    saveItem() {
        const newItem = {
            name: this.get('itemName'),
            description: this.get('itemDescription'),
            price: this.get('itemPrice')
        };
    }
}
```

The question is, how do I push the `newItem` object into model's `shopStock` array?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use another model for the `shopStock`?

Comment: The easy solution seems to be that you create another model called `shopStock` and change the `shop` model to have `DS.hasMany('shopStock', {() => []})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to create/edit/save/delete the related child records, you should create a new model for the child (shopStock) that belongsTo the parent (shop).

```
// app/models/shop-stock.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    price: DS.attr('string'),
    shop: DS.belongsTo('shop')
  })
});
```

Your shop model should also have another field added, `shopStocks: DS.hasMany('shop-stock')`.

When you want to add child records to the parent, you will use the `.pushObject()` method. See the [Model Relationships](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/models/relationships/) section of the Guides for more details.